# Proper Version Control and Bug Tracking

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2015, issue-tracking

So I have recently started using Visual Studio's Team Server to manage my code and track bugs. My question is, when fixing bugs and issues. Should I create an entire branch dedicated to fixing the bug and if so, should i clone the entire project into that branch or is the convention copying only the files related to the bug and fixing them there then pushing them to the master branch once the bug has been removed?

Comment: In git branches are always of the whole branch at once. If you already have a local clone, then creating that branch is a very simple process which will only take seconds.